# Is there a way to map a table that has a column which has more than one foreign key to a specific entity in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am using the imdb datasets and need some help.

I have this actor/director table, where nconst is the primary key of the table, and knownForTitles is a foreign key from the movie/series table.

**actor/director table**

[image]

**movie/series table**

[image]

The c1 column is the primary key of the movie/series table.

Here are my 2 **entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="moviesAndSeries")
@Data
public class SeriesAndMovies {

    @Id
    @Column(name="c1")
    private String tconst;

    @Column(name="c2")
    private String titleType;

    @Column(name="c3")
    private String primaryTitle;

    @Column(name="c4")
    private String actualTitle;

    @Column(name="c5")
    private Integer isAdult;

    @Column(name="c6")
    private Integer startYear;

    @Column(name="c7")
    private Integer endYear;

    @Column(name="c8")
    private Integer runTimeMinutes;

    @Column(name="c9")
    private String genres;

    public SeriesAndMovies() {
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="data")
@Data
public class ActorsAndDirectors {

    @Id
    @Column(name="nconst")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="primaryName")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="birthYear")
    private Integer birthYear;

    @Column(name="deathYear")
    private Integer deathYear;

    @Column(name="primaryProfession")
    private String profession;

    @Column(name="knownForTitles")
    private ??? popularTitles;

    public ActorsAndDirectors() {
    }

}
```

Is there a way to map this using jpa annotations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure to understand. Could you show us your present entities? or both columns?

Comment: I edited, maybe u can understand now

Comment: Please include the table structure/data into your question, and show us what you have tried. This way other people can understand your question even if the images are deleted.

Comment: Any ORM framework will be able to handle OneToMany relationship. But the underlying DB column for the FK in actor/director table will not look like the one you have (comma separated).

Comment: Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: No, because it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a dataset and a database.
Even if the data in the dataset are stored as a string representing a list of values, it is up to you to convert those values into entries in the right tables.

Mapping the column as a list of ids doesn't make sense in a relational database.
The correct way is to create an association between the two entities, using a [one-to-many](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many) or (a many-to-many):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="data")
@Data
public class ActorsAndDirectors {

    ...

    @OneToMany
    private Set<SeriesAndMovies> knownForTitles;


}
```

When you read the data from the dataset, you need to parse it and insert the right values in the right table or tables of the database.

Comment: The foreign keys are comma separated i dont think this will work

Comment: There is a difference between datasets and databases. I've expanded my answer